# Prove $S$ is not a superset of the power set of $S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

In my head, by definition it isn't true. The power set of $S$ is all possible subsets of $S$. $S$ is indeed a subset of the power set. Why is my homework problem hinting at doing a proof by contradiction. Is this not enough?

Comment: In general it's not true that $S$ is a subset of the power set of $S$. For instance, if $S=\{1\}$, then the power set is $\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$ and $\{1\}\not\subset\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$.

Comment: In fact $S$ isn't a subset of $P(S)$. It cannot be. It's an element of it. There's a difference.

Comment: @Ahmed Except in a very special case. `;-)`

Comment: Do you know about the cardinality of the power set of $S$?

Comment: The special case sparks infinitely many cases: $\emptyset\subset P(\emptyset)\subset P(P(\emptyset))\subset P(P(P(\emptyset)))\ldots $. In Von Neumann universe *every* $V_\alpha$ is a subset of its powerset.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote by $\mathcal{P}(S)$ the power set of $S$. Then, if $\mathcal{P}(S)\subseteq S$, we have $S\in S$, because $S\in\mathcal{P}(S)$.

Is it possible that $S\in S$ (under Zermelo-Fraenkel-Skolem axioms)?

Alternative proof: $|\mathcal{P}(S)|>|S|$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that what Russell's paradox really proves is that if $A$ is a set, then there is a subset of $A$, which is not an element of $A$.